# Symfony Finder ignores files beginning by dot

Tags: symfony, symfony-finder

I am using the Finder for sending spooled e-mails, but automatic name generator puts dots in the filename and sometimes they appear at the beginning of the file.

It seems that the finder can't get files with that name - well those files are hidden... Has anyone experienced that behaviour? Any advice how to use the finder to locate hidden files?

Thx

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just set [`ignoreDotFiles`](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Finder/Finder.html#method_ignoreDotFiles) to false.

```
$finder = new Finder();
$finder->files()->ignoreDotFiles(false)->in('directory');
```

For .git files, set ignoreVCS to false

```
$finder->files()
    ->ignoreVCS(false)
    ->ignoreDotFiles(false)->in('directory');
```

Comment: Additionally. Even if `ignoreDotFiles` is set to `false` but you are using bash wildcard pattern of filename it won't work.
So there you'd better use regular expression for name matching.