# Symfony finder, Ignore dot files doesn't work with FTP address

Tags: php, symfony, ftp, symfony-3.3

I'm using Symfony, and the component [Finder](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html). I want to get a file whose name begins with dot (".file.txt") and this file is in other server.

If I do this:

```
$finder
    ->files()
    ->ignoreDotFiles(false)
    ->in("ftp://user:pass@exmple.example:/myDir/")
;
```

1. I don't get any file but, if I rename the file and remove dot
   ("file.txt") then I can find it.
2. If I try to find files that start with dot in my local computer then
   it finds it well. [Like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21331144/symfony-finder-ignores-files-beginning-by-dot)

So my question is: Why the method `ignoreDotsFile` doesn't works when is ftp address?

Comment: The files with dot are destinated to be hidden. So the _logical_ solution should be that the file would not have a dot, because i need to read it.
But im not the admin of this file so i want find other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is very simple and clear, so if does not work is by a **bug** of [Finder + FTP](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html) component.

In fact FTP causes a lot of bugs like these:

[Options not working](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18013)

[Bad performance](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/16429)

[More](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18923)

If connects with a windows machine this code would work fine but the problem was with linux server.

Answer provided by: [Javier Eguiluz](https://github.com/javiereguiluz)